# Elisp recursive macro

Tags: macros, lisp, elisp

Trying to define resursive macro in elisp

```
(defmacro remacro (keys)
  (if keys
      `(func1 ,(car keys)
            ,(remacro (cdr keys)))
      ))



(macroexpand '(remacro '(a b c)))
```

But it is ended up in

```
 Lisp nesting exceeds `max-lisp-eval-depth'
```

error.

Wanted to get result like

```
(func1 a (func1 b (func1 c nil nil) '(c)) '(b c))
```

from

```
(remacro '(a b c))
```

Please let me know how I can correct this definition.

One more thing could I defined `keys' as rest parameter like

```
(defmacro remacro (&rest keys)
  (if keys
      `(abc ,(car keys)
            ,(remacro `,@(cdr keys)))
      ))
```

tried this one but it is not working.

USE CASE:

Basically I wanted to define a function

to set a tree node that is arranged in alist way

(it is still not working, have to work on it)

```
(defmacro set-tree-node (tree e &rest keys)
  `(setcdr
    ,(if keys
         `(assoc (car keys)
                 (pushnew
                  (list ,(car keys))
                  (cdr
                   ,(set-tree-node `(cdr ,xtree) e `,@(cdr keys)))
                  :key 'car))
         tree)
    e))


(setq egtree nil)
```

After running

```
(set-tree-node egtree new-node n b c)
```

should get

egtree eq

```
((n  (b  (c . new-node))))
```

or

```
(n  (b  (c . new-node)))
```

I had defined it as function

```
(defun set-tree-node (tree e &rest keys)
  (setcdr
   (reduce (lambda (xtree k)
             (message "tree %s k %s" xtree k)
             (assoc k (pushnew (list k) (cdr xtree) :key 'car)))
           keys :initial-value (cons nil tree))
   e))
```

But it could work only for existing list

It can successfully change (tree if full path exists)

```
  egtree from


  (setq egtree '((n  (b  (c . d)))))
```

to

```
  egtree eq


  '((n  (b  (c . replaced-d))))
```

after called like this

```
  (set-tree-node jt 'replaced-d 'n 'b 'c)
```

But this function do not work with if list if complete path do not
exits

Comment: Explain how you think that the control flow of this macro is supposed to work. What is your base case? Is it only supposed to work with abc? Where does the add come in? Where do you think you're printing (cdr keys)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the macro as:

```
(defmacro remacro (keys)
  (if keys
      `(abc ,(car keys)
            (remacro ,(cdr keys)))))
```

and call it:

```
(remacro (a b c))
```

You don't need to quote the argument because macro parameters are not evaluated.

To see the expansion, use:

```
(macroexpand-all '(remacro (a b c)))
(abc a (abc b (abc c nil)))
```

I don't see where `add` is supposed to come from in your example, I assume that was a typo for `abc`.

Comment: Also, M-x pp-macroexpand-last-sexp

Answer (score 0):

```
(defmacro tree-node (tree &rest keys)
  (if keys
      `(cdr
        (assoc ',(car (last keys))
               (pushnew
                ',(last keys)
                (tree-node ,tree ,@(butlast keys))
                :key 'car)))
    tree))


(setq egtree nil)
(setf (tree-node egtree l1 l2 lx) 'value)
(push (tree-node egtree l1 l2 ly) 'element1)
(push (tree-node egtree l1 l2 ly) 'element2)


(defmacro set-tree-node (tree value &rest keys)
  `(setf (tree-node ,tree ,@keys) ,value))


(set-tree-node egtree 'value l1 l2 lz)
```

wanted to make macro like this.